# Mock import to test class method

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest

I have a class that is a Django model:

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
```

The class has a few methods unrelated to the DB side (helpers/static methods, etc). However, when I import it, because it calls `django.db.models`, it also tries to use the Django settings to connect to the DB. I'm not sure how to properly mock this so it's workable but I can write unit tests for the extra methods. I'm using pytest, not the unittest built into Django.

Comment: While it is possible to mock the DB connection away, the way this is usually handled with django is to use the test db settings. You can configure django to use a local throw-away database when running tests. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: @blues I saw that, but that uses the internal `manage.py test` unittest, right? I can't figure out how to make that work with pytest.